# @ServerEndpoint( "/websocket") 404

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, websocket

I'm trying to implement this
http://www.byteslounge.com/tutorials/java-ee-html5-websocket-example

However I can't get it to map to /websocket on the class

```
@ServerEndpoint( "/websocket")
public class WebSocketController {


}
```

I can get a method to map using

```
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.OK)
@RequestMapping(value = "/websocket")
public WebSocketController<String> logError() {
}
```

But I can't use the same @RequestMapping on the Class, and @ServerEndpoint isn't having any effect.

Error is

```
 30217 [qtp351496750-25] WARN org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/websocket] in DispatcherServlet with name 'Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet'
```

Can anyone help!?

Comment: Maybe you should run it in java-ee container?

Comment: Hi! What kind of web server are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. The problem was the fact I'm using Spring and didn't add any details into web.xml.

```
<servlet>
    <description>AtmosphereServlet</description>
    <servlet-name>AtmosphereServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>org.atmosphere.cpr.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>*******</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>AtmosphereServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/websocket/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Have used Atmosphere and it's working well thanks